# Can I use uplevel/upvar instead of having to use global?

Tags: tcl

So, I am testing somethings out, and have a "test" proc like so:

```
proc test {arg} {
    global state
    puts "Your arg is: $arg"
    set state 1
}
test somearg
vwait state
```

From reading about uplevel and upvar, is there a way that I can get away with not having to use global, and use either one of those options to set the state to "1" and then exit the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, except that `vwait` always uses global variables for waiting on (strictly, it resolves variable names in the global scope; you can use other namespaces if you provide qualified names). What you can't do is wait on a local variable (because events can't see local variables outside their own call stack). Maybe this will change in the future, but certainly not now.

In relation to the question about `global`, these statements are all the same in effect inside a procedure:

```
global foo
variable ::foo
upvar #0 foo foo
upvar ::foo foo
namespace upvar :: foo foo
```

You also have a bug in your code: you set the state before waiting for it to change. That won't work anyway because you've got to wait first, and set the state from within some kind of event.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks! That "bug" was a typo on my part. I didn't mean to paste it in there. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for two different things.  First, about the variable.  You can use `upvar` like so:

```
proc test {arg} {
    upvar #0 state state
    puts "Your arg is: $arg"
    set state 1
}
```

Or, more easily, you can just use the namespace qualified name:

```
proc test {arg} {
  puts "Your arg is: $arg"
  set ::state 1
}
```

The second "half" of your question is some odd usage of `vwait`.  I just want to point out that your snippet of code won't complete because you're waiting for the variable 'state' to change, but there's no event that will ever change state.  You already changed it when you called `test`.  So, unless you've set up a window/button or something that might cause `state`'s state to change, your script will hang.

It's worth reading the [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1302) and the [man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/vwait.htm) for `vwait`.

Comment: I have another proc that I use to configure network devices, after I open a ssh session. I have a "vwait state" statement similar to the one above that I posted. And within the proc, I "set state 1" once the configuration is finished. This works without a problem. I'm just curious to see why my above example doesn't work...but I'll have to keep digging.